# How to scroll Recyclerview smoothly with inertia effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using Recyclerview in my app, i want to give inertia type effect to my scrolling so it doesn't stop suddenly at top and bottom of list, how can i achieve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a class which will be scrolled your recycler view.

#### Note: this class must necessary working in UI thread.

Something like that:

```
mTimer = new Timer();
mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
// delay 1000 ms repeat in 1000ms
mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 1000, 1000);

RecyclerView recyclerView;
float currentScrollY = 0;

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        currentScrollY += 5;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.scrollTo(0, currentScrollY);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

inertness mechanism you need implement by himself.

Comment: THis code exit with this exception.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.